# how to implement compare method in derived class?

Tags: c++, oop

Consider the following situation:

```
class Item
{
public:
    virtual bool Compare(const Item& InItem) = 0;
};

class Weapon : public Item
{
public:
    virtual bool Compare(const Item& InItem) override
    {
        const Weapon* InWeapon = dynamic_cast<const Weapon*>(&InItem);
        return InWeapon ? Damage == InWeapon->Damage : false;
    }

private:
    int Damage = 0;
};

class Armor : public Item
{
public:
    virtual bool Compare(const Item& InItem) override
    {
        const Armor* InArmor = dynamic_cast<const Armor*>(&InItem);
        return InArmor ? Defence == InArmor->Defence : false;
    }

private:
    int Defence = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Item* ItemInst = new Weapon();
    Item* ItemInst2 = new Weapon();

    if (ItemInst->Compare(*ItemInst2))
    {
        // ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I always implement Weapon Compare method using dynamic_cast ( like code above )

Is there any better way to achieve this? or is it best?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Using dynamic_cast in this context is a reasonable way to achieve polymorphic behavior when comparing objects of derived classes. It allows you to check if the given Item is of a specific derived type and then perform the comparison accordingly.
However, there is an alternative approach you can consider, which is to use a type identifier (e.g., an enumeration) within the Item class to indicate the type of the derived class. This can be especially useful if you have more derived classes in the future or if you want to avoid using dynamic_cast.

Comment: Suggestion: `a ? b : false` —> `a && b`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be a better fit for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is generally for when you're trying to solve a problem with non-working code. Here, the question is likely going to produce opinion-based answers, which makes it off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: "In general, there is no way to correctly implement the `equals()` contract to work in a class hierarchy, because of the symmetric requirement: `if x.equals(y) == true` then `y.equals(x) == true` as well."

Comment: @Jarod42 why would it not be implementable? If a `Weapon` only compares equal to other `Weapon`s, it looks symmetrical to me. This is basically Java's `.equal()`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, "compare" is not a good name for an equality predicate. A more obvious name would be `equals`. (Compare "if a equals b" to "if a compared to b is true". What does the latter even mean?)

Comment: @JanSchultke: Above implementation are wrong if we inherit from `Weapon`: `weapon.Compare(magicalWeapon)` != `magicalWeapon.Compare(weapon)`

Comment: @Jarod42 depends on how you implement it I guess. You'd have to ensure that a `MagicalWeapon` only compares equal to a `MagicalWeapon`, not to a `Weapon`.

Comment: According to the context, what you need is `isItemStatsEqualsTo()` which you must implement on your own. Ensure lhs and rhs are the same type then check the stats. So your code could be separated into two functions. 1. `isSameType()` 2. `isSameStat()` then your base class may implement `isItemStatsEqualsTo(const Item& y){return isSameType() && isSameStat();}` Then every derived class need to implement their own version of `isSameStat()`. Where `isSameType()` could use what @prabunaresh suggested. Then you don't need dynamic cast at all. Also reflection libraries might help for `isSameStat()`

Comment: @JanSchultke: Weapon can compare equal to magicalWeapon currently...

Comment: @Jarod42 you can add a `typeid` based check for exact type equality. It's clearly implementable, even if the current code doesn't have that functionality. Your claim is that it's unimplementable.

Comment: @JanSchultke: You also have to change `private` to `protected` to compare parent fields, (which is not always possible).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Comparable {
public:
virtual int compare(const Comparable& other) const = 0;
};

class MyClass : public Comparable {
private:
int data;
public:
MyClass(int value) : data(value) {}  
virtual int compare(const Comparable& other) const override {
    const MyClass* otherObject = dynamic_cast<const MyClass*>(&other);
    if (!otherObject) {
        cerr << "Comparison with incompatible type." << endl;
        return 0; 
    }

      if (data < otherObject->data) {
        return -1;
    } else if (data > otherObject->data) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0; 
    }
}
};

int main() {
MyClass obj1(10);
MyClass obj2(20);
int result = obj1.compare(obj2);
if (result < 0) {
    cout << "obj1 is less than obj2" << endl;
} else if (result > 0) {
    cout << "obj1 is greater than obj2" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "obj1 is equal to obj2" << endl;
}
return 0;``
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).